# Postgresql taking the first 1000 data and transferring 10 by 10 to another database on another server

Tags: postgresql

I have a 2 servers A and B. I wanted to take first 1000 data from A and transfer to B.
It need to create a same database and table in the B and import the data 10 by 10.

I need automation for this.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: What do you mean with "10 by 10"?

Comment: "*It need to create a same database*" - have you considered Postgres replication?

Comment: First, import first 10 data and second 10 data and third.... until first 1000 data is over. can replication do this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in chunks of 10? And why only the first 1000?

Comment: It is not my wish. It is an exam question. I just need a way to go. Not the solution. I want to do myself.

Comment: This is not an answerable question in itself. You'd either need to post the whole exam here, or apply the context of the course that we don't know about. I suggest asking your teacher.

Comment: It will create on server "B" with the same name as the database and table names on server "A" and transfers of the first 1000 data on server "A" to "B" servers 10 by 10. we are waiting for automation. I translated from turkish. I wish you understand exactly.